# jQuery: validating a field that was hidden at first

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Ok, this is pretty hard for me to explain but I'm going to do my best.

I have a single form that I have split up into 3 seperate steps to make it easier for the user to process the data. Thanks to jQuery, I'm easily able to do this by hiding and showing elements in the dom, but because of this also, jQuery is having trouble validating data that was hidden initially.

Please take a look at the following form: http://jsfiddle.net/Egyhc/

```
<form>
  <div id="step1" style="display: block;">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="first_name" id="FirstName"/>

    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="last_name" id="LastName"/>
  </div>


  <div id="step2" style="display: none;">
    <label for="first_name">Address</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="address" id="Address"/> 
  </div>

  <a href="#" id="step1_btn">Continue to step 2</a>
  <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Verstuur" style="display: none;" />
</form>


$(function() {
  $('#step1_btn').click(function() {
    $('#step1, #step1_btn').hide();
    $('#step2, #submit_btn').show();        
  });
});​
```

As you can see, it's a fairly simple form but when I add validation, only the first "step" works. The second step doesn't get validated.

Below you can find the code where I added the validation:

```
$(function() {
  $('#step1_btn').click(function() {
    $('form').validate({
      rules: { 
        first_name: "required",
        last_name: "required" 
      }
    });

    if($('form').valid()) {
      $('#step1, #step1_btn').hide();
      $('#step2, #submit_btn').show();   
    }     
  });


  $('#submit_btn').click(function() {
    $('form').validate({
      rules: { 
        address: "required"  
      }
    });

    if($('form').valid()) {
      return true
    }     
  });
});​
```

Anyone know how I can make the validation work once I get to the second step as well?

Comment: This looks like you're using the jQuery validation plugin. Do you have that loaded via a script tag? It's not in your fiddle.

Comment: Hidden elements is the same as non-hidden elements.

Comment: If hiding it gives you trouble, then you might want to try setting the height to `0px`. ;)

Comment: Where is your `step2_btn`, you have  `$('#step2_btn').click(...)` event.

Comment: @sheikheera: i fixed it. it should've been `submit_btn`
@shareef: this is just an example form, the real form is in my 2nd comment

Comment: i think the code you posted is note like your web site because of this difference you do the calculate <label for="first_name">Address</label> in websit address address

Comment: Glad you realized, so my answer will be soon.

Answer (score 3):

I've gave the form here because I've modified it (added a back link)

```
<form>
  <div id="step1" style="display: block;">
      <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" value="" name="first_name" id="FirstName"/>
      <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" value="" name="last_name" id="LastName"/>
  </div>
  <div id="step2" style="display: none;">
    <label for="first_name">Address</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="address" id="Address"/> 
  </div>

  <a href="#" id="step1_btn">Continue to step 2</a>
  <a href="#" id="step2_btn" style="display:none;" >Back to step 1</a>
  <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Verstuur" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('form').validate({
        rules: { 
          first_name: "required",
          last_name: "required",
          address: "required"  
        }
    });

    $('#step1_btn').click(function() {
        if($('form').valid()) {
            $('#step1, #step1_btn').hide();
            $('#step2, #submit_btn').show(); 
            $('#step2_btn').show();       
        }     
    });

    $('#step2_btn').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#step1, #step1_btn').show();
        $('#step2, #submit_btn').hide();  
    });            

    $('#submit_btn').click(function() {
        if($('form').valid()) {
            return true
        }     
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Egyhc/5/)

Comment: could you tell us the fix in short summarize or we have to compare ,i want to learn here

Comment: Check the update. I've declared all validation rules together inside `document.ready` event and finally validated the form on submit using `$('#submit_btn').click()` event.